# Store Button Android

Tags: android, arrays, button

I try to store some button into a array like this:

`Button Intro,Product;`

```
Button[]toogleButtons={Intro,Product};
private int[] ToogleButtonID = { R.id.tab2_info_intro,R.id.tab2_info_product };
```

after this I initialize the button :

```
private void iniToogleButton() {
    for (int i = 0; i < toogleButtons.length; i++) {
        toogleButtons[i] = (Button) findViewById(ToogleButtonID[i]);
        toogleButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}}
    Intro.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

And it get NullPointerException on Intro.setBackgroundColor();
Seen like I cant store those button and initialize with an array.

Any Idea or good way to make it posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
toogleButtons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

instead of

```
Intro.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

to change Button Background color because you are not initializing `Intro` Button instance before calling `setBackgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize Intro before calling setBackgroundColor(Color.RED).
Rename toogleButtons to buttons like this,

```
buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(ToogleButtonID[i]);
buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}}
Intro.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```